# Is there any website which offers Coldfusion Cloud IDE?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm looking for something similar to https://kodingen.com/

Thanks

Comment: Cloud9 does . http://c9.io/. @Chris Drappier: Why would this be a don't ask question? Just curious to understand the logic :)!

Comment: FWIW I think the tools you use to solve programming problems are as valid as the programming problems themselves.  I'm open to this being clarified.

Comment: @craig.kamisnky: Because at heart it's a shopping/"do my search for me" question. There's not a specific problem to be solved.

Comment: @AlEverett : Thank you for the explanation. I wasn't sure when I read the FAQs and was just trying to understand the logic so I better use SO. Appreciate it and have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the updated Kodingen, [Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh)? They give you a full Ubuntu VM now, with root!

After a bit of Googling for ColdFusion on Ubuntu, i see a lot of options, so check it out! I'm sure it will run on Koding :)

Answer (score -1):

You could run tmux, and inside tmux run something like vim, with a CFML library.  This in turn would allow you to ssh in from anywhere into a machine (such as a VPS or cloud machine) in which you could do all of your development.